# Java List<Byte> doesn't contain Bytes

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I really can't explain this one.
I have a Java `List<Byte> myList;` that is set like this:

```
class AJavaClass {
    // ...
    private List<Byte> myList;
    public AJavaClass(List<Byte> myList) { this.myList = myList; }
    // ...
}
AJavaClass aJavaClass = new AJavaClass(customMongoRepository.customFind());
```

The `customMongoRepository` object is injected via Spring. It is defined like this:

```
public interface CustomMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<AComplexClass, String> {
    List<Byte> customFind();
}
```

However, when looking inside `aJavaClass` during execution, `myList` is actually of type `List<AComplexClass>`.

Now, what I understand is that the query executed in `customFind` doesn't yield a `List<Byte>`, but rather a `List<AComplexClass>`. What I don't understand is how this doesn't throw an exception, and how a variable can contain a value of a different type.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn more about what Java does with generics. http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Why do instantiations of a parameterized type share the same runtime type?

Comment: During execution, all lists are `List<Object>` (or, to be more correct, just `List`). Check "type erasure" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens. And because of this, generics are for compile time checks only.